# Sorting collection_name in appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sorting

```
class Profile(db.Model):
    user = db.UserProperty()

class Playlist(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    profile = db.ReferenceProperty(Profile, collection_name='playlists')
    videos_num = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
```

This are the basic entities of my model. I can access the playlists like `profile.playlists` but how can I have them sorted according to their videos_num?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`profile.playlists` is just a db.Query. Call its `.order('videos_num')` method.